# How to select json data before loop in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I echo JSON data in PHP like this.

```
echo json_encode($row,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Then I use ajax in jquery and do for loop to loop the json data.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var img = data[i].url;
}
```

Ok, now here my problem.
I have a get_thumb(parem1, param2) php function and I want to use this function to
get the thumbnail image. How can I select the json url in php?
Like this

Edited

```
get_thumb($row[i]['url'], param2);
```

Comment: `get_thumb` is in PHP or Javascript? I'm so confused when looking at `$row[i].url` :(

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe get_thumb is php function

Comment: Is this `param2` available in json data on Javascript side. I think the first parameter `$row[i].url` maps to `data[i].url]`.

Comment: `param2` is different from each element of `$row` or the same?

Comment: param2 is the size of the thumbnail. It is an option like which size of thumbnail I want to select.

Comment: So you have the `$row` and the `$param2` on PHP, just loop through the `$row` array and add another member to its items with your `get_thumb` before using `json_encode`

Comment: @Trung-HieuLe So the looping is done in PHP not JS ?

Comment: Yes, prepare your data with all your information, just give the client the final result.

Comment: In this situation, is it possible to loop in client? I am thinking to  reduce the server load.

Comment: Yes, but you have to implement the `get_thumb` and pass the `param2` to client as well.